# Renumber rows based on createdDate

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm in need of a complicated SQL query. Essentially, there's a table called layer and it has a number of columns, the important ones being:

```
created_date, layer_id, layer_number, section_fk_id
```

The problem we have is there are some rows where layerId got duplicated per sectionFkId like this:

```
01/01/2021 4564 L01 1
03/01/2021 5689 L02 1
04/01/2021 6333 L02 1 <<problem row L02 duped
05/01/2021 8495 L03 1
03/01/2021 5603 L01 2
07/01/2021 6210 L02 2
10/01/2021 7345 L03 2
```

This would need to be fixed by incrementing layer id for those where duplicated and every row following so it ends up like this:

```
01/01/2021 4564 L01 1
03/01/2021 5689 L02 1
04/01/2021 6333 L03 1 << incremented layer id
05/01/2021 8495 L04 1 << incremented layer id
03/01/2021 5603 L01 2
07/01/2021 6210 L02 2
10/01/2021 7345 L03 2
```

Again, this is per sectionFkId.

Despite the terribly named column may suggest, layer_number is prefixed with an L and is therefore a varchar.

I've done the best I can in pseudocode, hoping someone can finish it:

```
startLayerId = L01
for each row in app.layer per section_fk_id order by created_date
  Update app.layer set layer_id = (startLayerId)
  startLayerId++
```

Comment: I'm a little confused.  Is `layer_number` a number or a string?

Comment: @GordonLinoff clarified. string. I didn't name the column :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` in an update.  Your description and pseudo-code suggest that `layer_number` is a number:

```
update layers l
    set layer_number = ll.seqnum
    from (select l.*,
                 row_number() over (partition by sectionFkId order by created_date) as seqnum
          from layers l
         ) ll
    where ll.sectionFkId = l.sectionFkId and
          ll.created_date = l.created_date;
```

If it is a string, you can use:

```
set l.layer_number = 'L' || lpad(ll.seqnum::text, 2, '0')
```

Comment: the SET part didn't like the alias, I just used layer_number not l.layer_number, however the rest worked great. Magic stuff.